# Cannot Add "Active Directory - Password" as Linked Server into my SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to add Azure Database with `Active Directory - Password` as Linked Server, but its giving error while login.

I'm using Domain account (for e.g. abc@my-domain.com and password)

These credentials are working and I'm able to connect normally BUT **NOT WORKING IN LINKED SERVER**

EDIT:
Adding the screenshots.
[image]

[image]

[image]

**ERROR DETAILS BELOW:**

> ===================================
>
> Create failed for LinkedServer ''.  (SqlManagerUI)
>
> ------------------------------ For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=14.0.17213.0+((SSMS_Rel).171128-2020)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+LinkedServer&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.LinkedServerPropertiesData.ApplyChanges()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.LinkedServerProperties.DoPreProcessExecution(RunType
> runType, ExecutionMode& executionResult)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.DoPreProcessExecutionAndRunViews(RunType
> runType)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.ExecuteForSql(PreProcessExecutionInfo
> executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.IExecutionAwareSqlControlCollection.PreProcessExecution(PreProcessExecutionInfo
> executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.RunNow(RunType
> runType, Object sender)
>
> ===================================
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
> batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
> sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection
> sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection
> queries, Boolean retry)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection
> queries, Boolean includeDbContext, Boolean executeForAlter)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImplFinish(StringCollection
> createQuery, ScriptingPreferences sp)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImpl()
>
> ===================================
>
> Name cannot be NULL. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> ------------------------------ For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=14.00.1000&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=15004&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ Server Name: . Error Number: 15004 Severity: 16 State: 1 Procedure: sys.sp_validname Line Number: 17
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction
> action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean
> catchException)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
> sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to use the new [Microsoft OLEDB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), aka "MSOLEDBSQL", not the old [Microsoft OLEDB Provider for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=%20Microsoft%20OLE%20DB%20Provider%20for%20SQL%20Server,Transact-SQL.%20%206%20See%20Also.%20%20More), aka "SQLOLEDB".  You can download it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

The old driver doesn't support Azure Active Directory Authentication.

Second you have to set the "Authentication" connection string keyword:

[image]

Then when you map the login using AAD credentials, the driver will interpret them correctly, and not try to use SQL Auth.

[image]

Or in script form:

```
USE [master]
EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropserver @server=N'AZURE', @droplogins='droplogins'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'AZURE', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'MSOLEDBSQL', @datasrc=N'xxxxxxx.database.windows.net', @provstr=N'Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword'

GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'AZURE', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False', @rmtuser = N'xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com', @rmtpassword = N'xxxxxxxxx'
GO
exec ('select 1 a') at AZURE
```